# Raspberry Pi 4: My Led blinks only 8 time when I expect it 16 times

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

Please, find the below screenshot of my program run, compilation, and result. As you see below from the LED blink numbers, I saw my LED blink only 8 times but I anticipated 16 times. How 16 times: blink every 0.25 s for 4s, this gives a total of 16. What is wrong? am I assuming something wrong?

My code:

```
 // include onoff to interact with RPi board GPIO pins
 var gpio = require("onoff").Gpio;
 // specify GPIO27 pin as output and we connected and LED+ resistor to this pin already 
 var ledPin = new gpio(27,'out');
 // set blinking time for 250 ms; Executing following line alone makes LED flash continuously
 var blinkInterval = setInterval(blinkLedFunction,250) 
 // Now define the blinkLedFunction
 var ledBlink = 0;
 function blinkLedFunction(){
       // Start blinking LED
       // Check if LED presently set to OFF or 0
       if (ledPin.readSync()===0){
             // Then, set this to ON
             ledBlink++;
             console.log("LED blink "+ledBlink)
             ledPin.writeSync(1);
             // else, set it off
      }else {ledPin.writeSync(0);}
}
// set turn off time of LED blinking for 5s
var stopBlinking = setTimeout(stopBlinkingFunction,4000);
// Now define the stopBlinkingFunction
function stopBlinkingFunction(){
       // stop the function 
       clearInterval(blinkInterval);
       // set ledPin to low
       ledPin.writeSync(0);
       // Unexport GPIO to free resources; I still don't know yet. Maybe, we freeing the pin, in this case 27, for use elsewhere
       ledPin.unexport();
       }
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Don't take it personally. People aren't downvoting you, they're downvoting your question.

Comment: Where in this code does the 16 vs. 8 come out? This is just a bunch of numbers. The comments are a good start, but the overall structure here is a bit cluttered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It lasts 4 seconds. You call blinkLedFunction every 250 ms. So you call it 16 times. 8 times to switch on the led. 8 times to switch it off. That is 8 "blinks".

Solution: either expect 8 blinks, or wait for 8 seconds, or call blinkLedFunction every 125 ms :D

Comment: Oho. This is how it works and I failed to get the logic. My question is answered. I appreciate the answer.

Comment: Can you please explain, why to use `ledPin.unexport()` and I just used it to get it working but I don't know why and what it does? Infact I ran my above script without it and it ran normally without any errors. But still it is used.

Comment: `unexport` means that this GPIO can no longer be controled from user space (through /sys/class/gpio filesystem). If a GPIO is not exported, then you can't read and/or set its value through those files. But, I guess, if it is, the kernel has to watch those "files" access (they are not really files, so it is not like it has to really write their content. It is only on demand. But still, I guess it is work, and that is the reason why it is better to advise the kernel you don't need it anymore). The Gpio class is just helper class to interact with those /sys/class/gpio "files".

Comment: @Mainland There might be some other reason. I don't know the internal of kernel interface to GPIO. But the point is, you need to "export" GPIO before using them (using Gpio class, that is done when calling the constructor `new gpio(27, 'out')`). And "unexport" when you no longer intend to interact with it.

Comment: It made a good sense now, when we defined `new gpio(27,'out')` we are saying to the board that we want to control it here from the console or IDE through the script and `.unexport()` we are basically saying to stop controlling this and any of the GPIO pins from the console. Thanks and I liked your explanation.